# Can I get a dump of my deleted question?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I had been searching for an old arcade game I used to play for years (the only one I played a lot, I was not a player). I thought gaming.stackexchange could help me, redacted a very detailed question ([Help identifying a late 80s arcade shooter game?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/22032/help-identifying-a-late-80s-arcade-shooter-game)) and thanks to a number of people that helped I finally found it, granted a bounty. It was a great moment, lots of people commented.

Now I wanted to check one thing on the question, and I entered gaming.stackexchange, as I never enter anymore (I'm no gamer) I had a notification I had the Popular question badge, I went to see the question and...it was deleted.

I asked in meta.stackoverflow and found out I cannot view it in any way, only a moderator could. So, could some moderator provide me with the question somehow so I can save it locally?

A reason why the question was deleted would be appreciated too.

thanks

Comment: Oops, hit the wrong close reason.  These questions [were voted off-topic](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/4168/6066) and are now disallowed, with the old ones deleted.  You should be able to use the [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/) to retrieve the content.  This shows the post, getting answers would be slightly more complicated: http://data.stackexchange.com/gaming/query/67753/find-deleted-questions-by-user

Comment: Well, as a 10k user I can offer you this [massive screenshot](http://img692.imageshack.us/img692/8718/itgdump.png). For the reason why it was deleted, see Matthew's comment above.

Comment: @lunboks some comments are missing I guess, but that's what I wanted yes, appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> I believe the Game you are talking about is time pilot '84
>
> http://www.arcade-museum.com/game_detail.php?game_id=10120

["Accepted" answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/22344/23) by [Murf](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/22344/revisions).